# Programmatically manipulating active RDP session

Tags: python, macos, bash, rdp

I've got Mac OSX running and want to programmatically manipulate a active RDP session to for instance, perform actions within a launched program within the session (dynamics specifically, yet woudn't hurt to know a universal way).

I don't know if this is possible. Currently using a RDP file to launch the RDP session with credentials and have the process ID of my active session, retrieved via NSWorkspace. With that I can do the basic stuff like closing my session again, yet i want to manipulate the session.

My RDP client currently is Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Would wish to reach my goal in either bash or python.

Comment: You meant programmatically, I assume?

Comment: @MKesper Yes. Sorry, i corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few ideas:

- Use [`Quartz` graphics library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartz-graphics) in Python to manipulate with RDP client window. Here is a good start: [How to list all windows from all workspaces in Python on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44232433/55075)
- [Use `libfreerdp` via `ctypes`](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/3201).
- Run RDP session under *[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)* and use tools such as [AutoHotKey, AutoIT or `xdottool`](https://superuser.com/a/1215306/87805). See: [How to programmatically control X11 forwarded apps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219460/21471)
- Use WinRM ([`pywinrm`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm)) instead of RDP to run remote commands/scripts. Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133262/55075). This can allow to run auto tools mentioned above (e.g. AHK script controlling the apps).
- Use [Python GUI automation library for simulating user interaction in apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42664/3474).
- See also: [GUI scipting for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/22896/3474).
- [Write an RDP client that dumps the pixels of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20905662/55075). E.g. WebRTC or using libFreeRDP.
- If RDP client runs via X11 protocol (Quartz), you can try to tap into X11 requests as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952788/55075).
- Use [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) and its [API](http://pub.freerdp.com/api/). Its client is compatible with Linux, macOS and Windows.