# How to list all windows from all workspaces in Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, fullscreen, quartz

The following Python 2 code prints list of all windows in the current workspace:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Quartz
for window in Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, Quartz.kCGNullWindowID):
    print("%s - %s" % (window['kCGWindowOwnerName'], window.get('kCGWindowName', u'Unknown').encode('ascii','ignore')))
```

Although it doesn't print the applications which are in full screen (as it's in another workspace).

How do I modify above script to list all windows from all desktops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following script should return window information on any desktop/workspace/display, fullscreen, and detailed information (coordinates, pid, titles, etc.):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Quartz
import time
from Quartz import CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID
from Foundation import NSSet, NSMutableSet

def windowList(wl):
    for v in wl:
        print ( 
        str(v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowOwnerPID') or '?').rjust(7) + 
            ' ' + str(v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowNumber') or '?').rjust(5) + 
            ' {' + ('' if v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowBounds') is None else ( 
                    str(int(v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowBounds').valueForKey_('X')))     + ',' + 
                    str(int(v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowBounds').valueForKey_('Y')))     + ',' + 
                    str(int(v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowBounds').valueForKey_('Width'))) + ',' + 
                    str(int(v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowBounds').valueForKey_('Height'))) 
                ) ).ljust(21) + '}' + 
            '\t[' + ((v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowOwnerName') or '') + ']') + 
            ('' if v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowName') is None else (' ' + 
            v.valueForKey_('kCGWindowName') or '')) 
        ).encode('utf8') # remove 'encode' for Python 3.x

wl1 = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID)
print('Move target window (or ignore)\n')
time.sleep(5)

print('PID'.rjust(7) + ' ' + 'WinID'.rjust(5) + '  ' + 'x,y,w,h'.ljust(21) + ' ' + '\t[Title] SubTitle')
print('-'.rjust(7,'-') + ' ' + '-'.rjust(5,'-') + '  ' + '-'.ljust(21,'-') + ' ' + '\t-------------------------------------------')

wl2 = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID)

w = NSMutableSet.setWithArray_(wl1)
w.minusSet_(NSSet.setWithArray_(wl2))

wl = Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo( Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionAll, Quartz.kCGNullWindowID)
wl = sorted(wl, key=lambda k: k.valueForKey_('kCGWindowOwnerPID'))

windowList(wl)

print('\nDetailed window information: {0}\n'.format(w))
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is here to use the right option for the 1st argument of `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`. So apart of using [`optionOnScreenOnly`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/1454105-optiononscreenonly) property (which list all windows that are currently onscreen), [`excludeDesktopElements`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/1455528-excludedesktopelements) property needs to be added.

> [`excludeDesktopElements`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/1455528-excludedesktopelements): Exclude any windows from the list that are elements of the desktop, including the background picture and desktop icons.

E.g.

```
list = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements | kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID)
```

---

Alternatively for all windows, [`kCGWindowListOptionAll`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/kcgwindowlistoptionall) property can be also used.

> [`kCGWindowListOptionAll`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/kcgwindowlistoptionall): List all windows, including both onscreen and offscreen windows. When retrieving a list with this option, the `relativeToWindow` parameter should be set to `kCGNullWindowID`.

For other properties, check [`CGWindow.h` in `CoreGraphics`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_8/CoreGraphics.html).

---

So the original code can be changed to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Prints list of all windows.
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44232433/55075
import Quartz
for window in Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | Quartz.kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, Quartz.kCGNullWindowID):
    print("%s - %s" % (window['kCGWindowOwnerName'], window.get('kCGWindowName', u'Unknown').encode('ascii','ignore')))
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a bitwise or?